# How to convert key value from result to uppercase in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

Model class:

```
public class User
{
    public string NS_ID { get; set; }
    public string TONV_ABC { get; set; }
    public string NAME_ABC { get; set; }
    public string MAABC { get; set; }
}
```

Result json when testing in Postman:

```
    "nS_ID": "",
    "tonV_ABC": "",
    "namE_ABC": "",
    "maabc": "F02",
```

This is the result I want:

```
    "NS_ID": "",
    "TONV_ABC": "",
    "NAME_ABC": "",
    "MAABC": "F02",
```

This is my API:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("test")]
    public ActionResult test()
    {
        User u = new User();
        u.NS_ID = "";
        u.TONV_ABC = "";
        u.NAME_ABC = "";
        u.MAABC = "F02";
        return Ok(u);
    }
```

Please help me

I try convert but it's not working

Comment: didn't get you, can you explain more

Comment: I want to keep the names of the fields in the model in the json return result when call api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.net 7**: You just need to add the following configuration to `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
         options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    });
```

**.net core 3.1:**

add the following configuration to `startup.cs` :(`ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`)

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy= null;
    );
```

Comment: @viveknuna Your answer is really wrong. I have no enmity with you

Comment: @hosseinsabziani how are you deciding that is it wrong? can you explain?

Comment: @viveknuna in `.net core 3.1` Default mode for `JsonSerializerOptions` is `camel-casing`. Even if you send items with UpperCase, the first word will be lowercase in the result... you can test this

Comment: @viveknuna Even if you read the comments of the person who asked the question, you will realize that your answer was chosen incorrectly

Comment: @viveknuna in `.net core 3.1` Default mode for `JsonSerializerOptions` is `camel-casing`. Even if you send items with UpperCase, the first word will be lowercase in the result... you can test this...

Comment: @hosseinsabziani I have edited my answer, but you have to try and update that what was wrong in my answer. and other answers also if you did the same with those answers as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try to deserialize the JSON string to a `Dictionary<string, object>`. then create another Dictionary. iterate over the first dictionary and add all the key-value pairs to the new dictionary why making the key to upper case using the `ToUpper()` method. then serialize the new dictionary to the JSON string.

**Sample code:**

```
Dictionary<string, object> jsonDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);
Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in jsonDictionary)
{
    result.Add(kvp.Key.ToUpper(), kvp.Value);
}
string resultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

**Note**: I have used [NewtonSoft.json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json). you can get it from the Nuget package manager.

Comment: Is there a simpler way?

Comment: @kai this is very simple

Comment: can you help me, i'm not familiar with net core

Comment: i thank you very much, i got another solution but also thank you